# Object Conversion utitilty

Tags: java, apache-commons

I'm looking for an alternative to ConvertUtilsBean from Apache Commons. I simply need to convert a value to an object of a specified class, in other words, a method like this:

```
Object convert(Object value, Class targetType)
```

I would like to know what light-weight options are there that are as efficient.
Note: this option should not use Commons Logging and replacing commons logging with SLF4J is not a viable option either. I have suggested this approach, but for some reason it is required that commons-beanutils is not a included.

Comment: great! and what is your question?

Comment: The part that says "I'm looking for..." seems clear enough, but I added more detail JIC.

Comment: The secret is implementing the converter. A class to use it is simple like @ursa replied

Answer (score 1):

You can use the most efficient/lightweight solution - handwritten. Below is just an example, how it can be implemented:

```
public interface Converter<F, T> {
    T convert(F from);
}

public final class Converters {
    private final Map<Class<?>, Converter<?, ?>> converters; // initialize as you want

    public <F> void register(Converter<F, ?> converter, Class<F> fromClass) {
        converters.put(fromClass, converter);
    }

    public <T> T convert(Object input) {
        if (input == null) throw NPE;
        return (T) converters.get(input.getClass()).convert(input);
    }
}
```